# Statistic to choose for creating annual temperature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, cell-statistics

I have rasters of average minimum temperature from 2012-2021 i.e. for each year I have 12 rasters containing information of average minimum temperature for each month. I now want to combine all the 12 rasters of a particular year to get annual minimum temperature of that year.

I am planning to use Cell Statistic tool in ArcGIS however, am not sure which statistic to choose. Like should I choose mean however, that doesn't make sense as the individual rasters are already a mean.

Any insights on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what value you want to calculate.

The mean minimum temperature in a year is calculated by taking the average of all the daily minimum temperatures. If you first calculate the mean minimum temperature for each month, and then take the average of those, this is not the mean minimum temperature for the year, but rather the mean *monthly* minimum temperature. These two values will be close together, but in most cases, the difference between them will be non-zero.

To see why, let's consider the average minimum temps over just January and February. Say that the minimum temp was 0 for every day in Jan, and 1 for every day in Feb. The average minimum temp for Jan would then be 0, the average minimum temp for Feb would be 1, and the average of those two values is clearly 0.5. However, if we instead calculated the average minimum temp of the 59 total days in Jan+Feb, we get (31 * 0 + 28 * 1) / 59 = 0.47457.

If January and February had the same number of days, those two numbers would be the same. But since the months of the year do not all have the same number of days, taking the mean of the monthly averages will not produce the yearly average.

However, it is still possible to find the mean annual minimum temperature from the monthly averages, using the [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm) function. It is more work than simply using the Cell Statistics Mean, but one way to find the actual annual mean would be to "weight" each monthly raster by the number of days in that month:

```
("January" * 31 + "February" * 28 + ... + "December" * 31) / 365
```